# is there any way to send async messages to every renderer process in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I'm trying to build a simple weather app.

I have two renderer processes 1.`main_ui` window 2.`settings` window.

`settings` window is created from `main_ui` window.
now I want to choose a city name from the `settings` window so that the weather info for the city can be displayed on `main_ui` window. How can I achieve it?

> settings.js

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var city_id = document.getElementById("city_code");
var city_name = document.getElementById("city_name");
submit.addEventListener('click', () => { 
ipcRenderer.send('set_city_name', 
document.getElementById('city_name').value);
console.log(document.getElementById('city_name').value);})
```

> main.js

```
ipcMain.on('set_city_name', (event, arg) => {
console.log("got it");
console.log(arg);
event.sender.send('reply', arg);
});
```

but I know that `event.sender.send()` will reply to the `settings` window. how can i catch `reply` on `main_ui` ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to send async messages to every renderer process in electron?

Yes, you can one-by-one

```js
const {webContents} = require('electron')
webContents.getAllWebContents().forEach(wc => {
  wc.send('reply', arg)
})
```

---

For your actual problem, you could design the processes better to avoid such situations:

- If two processes have so much in common they can be one process but a complex html with different views
- If those processes are so important, your main process could call them directly